# Caching is working for one hour while it should be for days

Tags: caching, .net-core, memorycache

I have created an API using .NETCore 2.0 ; This API is connected to an oracle database to retrieve needed data; One of the functions takes too much time so I decided to use caching in order to retrieve data faster;

**Function description:** Get ranking

**Caching period:** Data should be renewed in cache memory each Monday

I am using `IMemoryCache`, but the problem is that data is not being cached for multiple days; It lasts only for one hour, after that data is being retrieved from database and takes too much time (10 s.); Below is my code:

```
var dateNow = DateTime.Now;

int diff = 7; // if today is Monday then should add 7 days to get next Monday date

if (dateNow.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) {
    var daysToStartWeek = dateNow.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
    diff = (7 - (daysToStartWeek)) % 7;
}

var nextMonday = dateNow.AddDays(diff).Date;
var totalDays = (nextMonday - dateNow).TotalDays;

if (_cache.TryGetValue("GetRanking", out IEnumerable<GetRankingStruct> objRanking))                   
    {
         return Ok(objRanking);
    }

var dp = new DataProvider(Configuration);
var response = dp.GetRanking(userName, asAtDate);

_cache.Set("GetRanking", response, TimeSpan.FromDays(diff));

return Ok(response);
```

Could be related to the token life Time since it's only 1 hour?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - have you tried checking to see if your worker process is being restarted?  You don't specify how you are hosting your application but, obviously, if the application (worker process) is restarted your memory cache will be empty.
If your worker process / process is restarting then you could load the cache on start up.

Secondly - I believe that the implementation may choose to empty the cache due to inactivity or memory constraints.  You can set the priority to never remove - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheitempriority?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1
I believe you can set this by passing a MemoryCacheOptions object to the constructor of the memory cache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCache__ctor_Microsoft_Extensions_Options_IOptions_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCacheOptions__.

Finally - I assume you've made your _cache object static so it is shared by all instances of your class.  (Or made the controller, if that's what it is, a singleton).

These are my suggestions.
Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your reply; Actually I am publishing on a webserver - windows server 2016; the application has never been restarted on the IIS;

Comment: cache is defined in the constructor of the controller as `public UserController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache cache) {  Configuration = configuration; _cache = cache;  }`

Comment: I have updated my code as  `MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();  options.Priority = CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove;  options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);    _cache.Set("GetRanking", response, options);` but with no luck; After 60 minutes from the first call, data is returned from database;

Comment: "windows server 2016; the application has never been restarted on the IIS" - IIS will automatically restart - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart/ usually its 29 hours - but might be worth checking on your server.

Comment: "ache is defined in the constructor of the controller" - it appears to be passed in - so you need to check that there is only one constructed.  i.e. the class where the new is called is a singleton / static or the object is a singleton/static i.e. some when of guaranteeing only one instance of the cache is created.  That being said, the 60minutes points (to me) more to an IIS setting.

Comment: I have discovered something very interesting; I realized that whenever the worker process shuts down in the IIS, the cache is reset; What do you suggest? I found that we can change the **IDLE Time-out**  to 0 minutes, that way it will never shut down. Do you agree with that? Doesn't have any bad impact on CPU ?

Comment: Yes - as I suggested - an worker process reset will empty the memory cache!  There is no memory impact on 0 (run forever) but the risk is if you have resource leaks - memory, diosck, I/o connection etc. they never get freed.  I think Microsoft put this in as a catch all for leaks.  Theirs as well as ours!

Comment: I have ended up by using **redis**, since it won't be affected by any stopped worker process; Then I have returned value of IDLE Time-out to 20;